# Can't able to fetch the User Profile photo in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api, slrequest

I am trying to get the facebook account details using `SLRequest` in ios.

I got all the details But **Can not able to get the Profile Photo link of the User.**

My code is as follow:

```
NSDictionary *options = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                         @"xxxxxxxxxxxxxx", ACFacebookAppIdKey,
                         [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"email", nil] , ACFacebookPermissionsKey,
                         nil];

[_accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:facebookTypeAccount
                                       options:options
                                    completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
                                        if(granted){
                                            NSArray *accounts = [_accountStore accountsWithAccountType:facebookTypeAccount];
                                            _facebookAccount = [accounts lastObject];
                                            NSLog(@"Success");

                                            [self me];
                                        }else{
                                            // ouch
                                            NSLog(@"Fail");
                                            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
                                        }
                                    }];


- (void)me{
NSURL *meurl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me"];


    SLRequest *merequest = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook
                                              requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET
                                                        URL:meurl
                                                 parameters:nil];

    merequest.account = _facebookAccount;

    [merequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
        NSString *meDataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSLog(@"%@", meDataString);

        NSJSONSerialization *js=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];
        NSLog(@"%@",js);

    }];

}
```

**Help me to solve this.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the user's ID from the returned response, then use the below to get the profile picture:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/User_ID/picture
```

I use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) for images:

```
NSString *urlstr = @"http://graph.facebook.com/100001393655684/picture";

[imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlstr]
                   placeholderImage:nil];
```

For Twitter, please make sure you authenticate your request, check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18917651/how-to-get-twitter-profile-picture-in-ios) for more details

Note: You may need to update TWRequest to SLRequest if you aren't deploying for iOS5

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I already tried this but got the null response.

Comment: are you sure the user ID is correct? please post the ID you use

Comment: well, it returns an elephant with a guitar for me, may be you need to check your network settings

Comment: then why I got the null response?

Comment: Okey!! Thats Great! What about Twitter?

Comment: I accepted your answer!! But Can you help me for Twitter also?

Comment: for twitter, send a get request to `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?screen_name=username`, you should get a link to the profile image in the returned JSON response

Comment: No , I am not able to get it.

Comment: chintan123 & Thanks a lot for your response.

Comment: check the answers, not the question :)    , there are complete codes there